# What is the difference between server_name _ and server_name "" in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I want to set a default catch-all server block to handle any host names that do not match my exact `server_name` values. But I'm unsure which one should I use.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name ""; # this is by default if no server_name specified
    return 444;
}
```

or

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

I've tested and they seem to behave equally. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names)

Comment: And this one: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 30):

Short answer: Yes, there is difference between `server_name "";` and `server_name _;`

Long answer:  `server_name "";` **defines a match for a request without** `host` **header** since 0.8.48 and it has been supported since 0.7.12.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

> If requests without the “Host” header field should not be allowed, a
>   server that just drops the requests can be defined:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen      80;
>     server_name "";
>     return      444;
> }
> ```
>
> Here, the server name is set to an empty string that will match
>   requests without the “Host” header field, and a special nginx’s
>   non-standard code 444 is returned that closes the connection.

On the other side, `server_name _;` defines an invalid server names which never intersect with any real name. It is just a non-match. So in the event of no matches, nginx will select the first server{} block and use that.

To conclude, you can use `server_name _;` for catch-all server block but not `server_name "";`.

Reference -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454764/nginx-server-name-wildcard-or-catch-all
https://blog.gahooa.com/2013/08/21/nginx-how-to-specify-a-default-server/

Comment: Worth noting that you need to use `HTTP 1.0` (`-0` paramter in `curl`) to test the `server_name ""` server block. `curl -v -0 -H "Host:" http://localhost`. See the accepted answer from https://serverfault.com/a/920459/485927

Comment: I wonder, why do we need `server_name _;` directive when we have `listen` with `default_server`? Is this for informational purposes?

Comment: I recommend to read this --> https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html