# Http request not caught by nginx server block?

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx server with exactly one site configuration (the default site).

I keep seeing the following lines in my access.log

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [10/Jul/2018:16:32:14 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "-"
```

I know for a fact that this happens if the request doesn't send a `Host:`header, as in `curl -v -H "Host:" https://{{ server_ip }}`

```
root@mypc:~# curl -v -H "Host:" http://{{ server_ip }}
* Rebuilt URL to: http://{{ server_ip }}/
*   Trying {{ server_ip }}...
* Connected to {{ server_ip }} ({{ server_ip }}) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 08:14:07 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 182
< Connection: close
<
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

**I did configure my site to respond to requests with no `Host:` header with an 444 error code. Obviously, this doesn't work. I assume I did misunderstand the docs and my config is incorrect. I would be glad if someone could point out what's missing:**

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ hostname_fqdn }}/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ hostname_fqdn }}/privkey.pem;

# Respond to requests without a host header with HTTP status 444
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name "";
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name {{ hostname_fqdn }};

    if ($allowed_country = no) {
        return 444;
    }

    return 301 https://{{ hostname_fqdn }}$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name {{ hostname_fqdn }};

    if ($allowed_country = no) {
        return 444;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/{{ django_project_name }}/socket;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root {{ django_static_root }};
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443 ssl;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name api.zeitschrift.hausbesitzerverlag.de;

    if ($allowed_country = no) {
        return 444;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/{{ django_project_name }}/socket;
    }

    location /pmx-api/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

        limit_req zone=api burst=5;

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/{{ django_project_name }}/socket;
    }

    location /komtrigon-api/ {
        limit_req zone=api burst=5;

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/{{ django_project_name }}/socket;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root {{ django_static_root }};
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are getting a Bad request, because you are using http in the Host header http://{{ server_ip }}

Comment: Nah, just `-H "Host:"`. I think you missed the ending quote.

Comment: Now is clear, you are sending the Host header without any value :)

Comment: @c4f4t0r `-H "Host:"` does not send the `host` header at all.

Comment: @Rick  Host: without nothing is invalid "curl -vv -H "Host: hello.com" google.com" * Connected to google.com (172.217.23.174) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: hello.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*

Comment: @c4f4t0r Yes, with `HTTP/1.0` it's valid.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP requests without a `Host:` header are not valid in HTTP/1.1 (or later), and nginx is correctly sending a 400 Bad Request error without even attempting to serve it with *any* `server` block. From [RFC 7230 section 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4):

> A server MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any
> HTTP/1.1 request message that lacks a Host header field and to any
> request message that contains more than one Host header field or a
> Host header field with an invalid field-value.

Your `server` block which serves requests without a `Host:` header will only be hit when a request comes in with the ancient HTTP/1.0. You can simulate this using `curl` with the `-0` command line option:

```
curl -v -0 http://203.0.113.87/
```

From the man page:

```
       -0, --http1.0
              (HTTP)  Tells  curl to use HTTP version 1.0 instead of using its
              internally preferred HTTP version.
```

Comment: Hey Michael, your answer seemed plausible, but then I figured out that the 400-code was served by the application behind it, so it wasn't nginx that returned the 400. Guess they don't follow that RFC. But I noticed that the spammers were doing a https-request, which made me aware that the default server didn't listen to ssl requests. Rookie mistake. Still, thanks for making me aware about that RFC. It's good to know!

Comment: @Daniel Michael is right about this. Try a plain nginx server. Set a `sever` block with `server_name ""`, and test it without the `Host` header by `curl -v -H "Host:" http://localhost`, you can't reach that `server` block. But you can reach it with additional  `-0`.

Answer (score 0):

Beginner's mistake. I forgot to add `listen 443 ssl default_server;` to the first server block.

```
...

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name "";
    return 444;
}

...
```

Although Micheal is completely correct about the RFC, it wasn't true in regards on how nginx works, as nginx has no built-in functionality that returns a 400 in that case.

It also didn't specifically answer my question. Since 10 out of 10 times my web server receives a request without host header, the request is sent by a spammer, I decided to ignore the RFC and just close the connection without letting the spammer know (`return 444;`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood something.

> I did configure my site to respond to requests with no Host: header with an 444 error code. Obviously, this doesn't work.

You does not configure **specifically** your site to respond to requests with no `Host` header with `444`.

It is: you configure your site that any `host` value that do not match other `server_name` value in `server` blocks, will come to the `default_server` block.

It's the `default_server` directive that actually matters. you can put any logically invaild value in `server_name`, within the `default server`, `server` block.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

> There is nothing special about this name(`server_name ""`), it is just one of a myriad of invalid domain names which never intersect with any real name. Other invalid names like “--” and “!@#” may equally be used.